# Unable to use the domain name assigned to a webapp in another Azure subscription even after deleting the resource

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I was working on an ARM template in my personal subscription. Once I got the correct template, I deleted all the resources that I had created in my personal subscription. When I am executing the same ARM template in a prod subscription, I am getting the error indicating that the webapps with that name are already taken. I am not sure how I can release them.

I have deleted all the resources from my personal subscription

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you try to recreate the webapp in another tenant. It is protection against hostile subdomain takeovers, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-dangling-subdomain-prevention#how-app-service-prevents-subdomain-takeovers):

> Upon deletion of an App Service app or App Service Environment (ASE), immediate reuse of the corresponding DNS is forbidden except for subscriptions belonging to the tenant of the subscription that originally owned the DNS. Thus, the customer is afforded some time to either clean-up any associations/pointers to the said DNS or reclaim the DNS in Azure by recreating the resource with the same name. This behavior is enabled by default on Azure App Service for "*.azurewebsites.net" and "*.appserviceenvironment.net" resources, so it doesn't require any customer configuration.

I've read somewhere it can take up to 30 days but you can contact support to speed things up.

Comment: I wanted to contact MS Support. As I do not have paid support, the support system asked me to log the support request here. I was hoping MS is monitoring this and would help me resolve this